# how do you mark a block/column in powerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I love the visuals of powershell ISE,

but I cannot find how to mark a column or a block in a similar way to cmd.exe's "right button > Mark"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can with PowerShell V2 but in V3 you hold the Alt key while you drag select to copy a set of columns.

Comment: Yes but V3 is only at beta status.  I wouldn't put it on production servers but I do have it installed on my dev machines.

Comment: Just in case someone else looks here. V3 is now officially released. It does require the full .NET 4 SDK to be installed. If you only have the 'Client Profile', then the msu will give a cryptic error about the update not applying to your system.